# Get data in servlet then Send data when initialization jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want get data in servlet then Send data when initialization jsp page.
I have masterpage same this:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>AAAAAAAAA</div>
        <div>
            <table border="1" id="table1">
                ${insert_data_here_1}
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>BBBBBBBBBBB</div>
        <div><table border="1" id="table2">${insert_data_here_2}</table></div>
        <div>CCCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And page ExtendMasterPage extend masterpage. Code same this:

```
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Extend</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        PageStack pS= new PageStack();
        List<String> lstResult= pS.getData();
    %>
    <form action="PageStack" method="get">
        <%@include file="masterPageStack.jsp" %>
        <table border="1" id="table1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= lstResult.get(0) %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="1" id="table2">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= lstResult.get(1) %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

And code in servlet of page ExtendMasterPage. when I run the code, the data is not added to the  insert_data_here_1 and insert_data_here_2.I don't understand why it does not work? And solution for this problem? Somebody help me!

```
 public List<String> getData(){
    List<String> lstResult= new ArrayList<String>();
    lstResult.add("Test1");
    lstResult.add("Test2");
    return lstResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not populating the variable and trying to use it. You could so something like:

```
<%= session.setAttribute("insert_data_here_2", lstResult.get(1)); %>
```

Instead of

```
<%= lstResult.get(1) %>
```

Comment: Sorry but it does not work. Because "session.setAttribute("insert_data_here_2", lstResult.get(1));" return void. When build have errors. Help!

Comment: thank you for support. I'm do it. Your idea is 
` <% session.setAttribute("insert_data_here_2", lstResult.get(1)); %> .

Comment: SMA I just do as you say. But when i run code in the first time, it does not work if i reload this page it work. I don't understand??? You know why?  Help me! Thank you for support me.

Comment: I just do as you say. But when i run code in the first time, it does not work if i reload this page it work. I don't understand??? You know why?  I want it work in first time.Help me! Thank you for support me.

Comment: You must be calling your jsp first and then populate your list. So populate list first and then load jsp.

Comment: i don't understand your idea. Please help me explain further by code.